# how to use muiti middleware for routes in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

I have middleware groups:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admins','web']], function () {
    Route::get('/change_mail/{num?}','LoginController@change_mail')->name('change_mail');
    Route::post('/change_mail', 'LoginController@post_change_mail');        
});
```

When I log in with a user account and use route `'change_mail',` it still redirects to login page although successful logged in.

What is wrong in my route?

Please help!

Comment: Try putting `web` before `auth:admins`

Comment: Not so sure, but i think removing the auth from auth:admin will help
['middleware' => ['admins', 'web']]

Comment: it show same result @apokryfos

Comment: it will show error: Class admins does not exist @avinashw50w

Comment: Is that route group defined inside `web.php` or is it in the route service provider?

Comment: it defined inside web.php @apokryfos

Comment: Remove the `web` middleware group then. Everything in `web.php` is already using that. Problem might be that you're starting the session twice

Comment: no, guard is default guard in auth of laravel, i cant remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was tried:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admins,web']], function () {
    Route::get('/change_mail/{num?}','LoginController@change_mail')->name('change_mail');
    Route::post('/change_mail', 'LoginController@post_change_mail');        
});
```

and it is working